# Is it okay to have a lot of segues between view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

So I'm quite new to iOS developing and have decided to venture down the swift path. I'm now working with multiple view controllers and passing data between, and what I'm wondering is if it is bad practice to have multiple (like 9-15) segues between 2 view controllers?

Basically what I have is a normal VC with 9 different buttons. Now, what I want is for each button to send different data to the subsequent tabbed VC instead of having a different VC for each button/catagory.

it would look something like this :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let tabBarController = segue.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController
    let svc = tabBarController.viewControllers![0] as! InfoViewController
    let svc2 = tabBarController.viewControllers![1] as! DIYViewController

    if segue.identifier == "wind" {
        svc.titleString = "Wind Power... what a powerful thing"

    } else if segue.identifier == "geothermal" {
        //send info about geothermal
    } else if segue.identifier == "hydroelectric" {
        //send infor about hydroelectricity
    } else if segue.identifier == "" {
        //code
    } else if segue.identifier == "" {
        //code
    } else if segue.identifier == "" {
        //code
    } else if segue.identifier == "" {
        //code
    }
}
```

is there a more conventional way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have only one segue, and pass the data in `prepareForSegue(_:sender:)`. E.g. In your first view controller, you pass the variable:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var myVariable: String!
    @IBAction func button1Action(sender: AnyObject) {
        myVariable = "Hello"
    }
    @IBAction func button2Action(sender: AnyObject) {
        myVariable = "Hola"
    }
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue == "MySegue" {
            let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
            secondViewController.myVariable = myVariable
        }
    }
}
```

And in your second view controller, you can do whatever you want with your variable:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var myVariable: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        title = myVariable
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I'm now running into the question of how to organize my data... Let's say I have 5 buttons, and each will send 10 different variables to populate the subsequest VC accordingly. 
Should I continue as you described, creating and setting each variable when the button is pressed? or does it make sense to create a separate file/class that holds this variables to be called upon.

Comment: ideally, I would like to end up being able to add to those variables from a database soon so I'm wondering if theres a more conventional organization that might follow the MVC protocol

Comment: ah.. seems like someone had already answered my question below, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `NSObject` subclass (e.g. `MyAtmospherologyObject`) and put all the needed properties within to store all the info for all 9 categories you might needed.

Then give it a *type* property and use `enum` for the only segue to determine what it was getting and how it should handle the rest of the data.

After this, you only need to send one object, which is the `MyAtmospherologyObject`. This could be useful as you can pass around the object anywhere as a whole once you initialized it, and reuse it from there.

e.g. **Objective-C** (I know it's not Swift, but you get the idea.)

**MyAtmospherologyObject.h**

```
//
//  MyAtmospherologyObject.h
//

@import Foundation;

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, MyAtmospherologyType) {
    MyAtmospherologyGeothermalType   = 0,
    MyAtmospherologyHydroelectricType
};

@interface MyAtmospherologyObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic)           MyAtmospherologyType type;
@property (nonatomic, strong)   NSString *mySting;

- (MyAtmospherologyType)type;

@end
```

**MyAtmospherologyObject.m**

```
//
//  MyAtmospherologyObject.m
//

#import "MyAtmospherologyObject.h"

@implementation MyAtmospherologyObject

- (instancetype)initWithType:(MyAtmospherologyType)aType
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _type = aType;
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - NSKeyedArchiver

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _type       = [decoder decodeIntegerForKey:@"type"];
        _mySting    = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"mySting"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeInteger:_type    forKey:@"type"];
    [encoder encodeObject:_mySting  forKey:@"mySting"];
}

#pragma mark - Methods

- (MyAtmospherologyObject)type
{
    return _type;
}

@end
```

**MyAtmospherologyViewController.m**

```
// ...

#import "MyAtmospherologyObject.h"

@implementation MyAtmospherologyViewController

// ...

- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
    MTKGSJournalQuestionnaireObject *object = [[MTKGSJournalQuestionnaireObject alloc] initWithType:MyAtmospherologyGeothermalType];
    object.myString = @"aString";
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegueIdentifier"
                              sender:object];
}

#pragma mark - UIStoryboardSegue

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    MyAtmospherologyObject *object = (MyAtmospherologyObject *)sender;
    MyAtmospherologySegueViewController *vc = (MyAtmospherologySegueViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

    switch (object.type) {
        case MyAtmospherologyGeothermalType:
            vc.navigationItem.title = object.myString;
            break;
        case MyAtmospherologyHydroelectricType:
            vc.navigationItem.title = object.myString;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

// ...

@end
```

Comment: in your viewcontroller.m class, is it necessary to use the switch-case statements? It just seems as though you are doing the same thing in either case so I'm wondering is just setting it as :
 
 `vc.navigation.title = object.myString; //enough?`

Comment: It's just an example, in case you might need to do different things for different type. If you don't care, then sure, you are fine without the switch. It's the same object after all.

Comment: Thanks, makes a lot of sense! I'm also wondering about another issue, in your IBAction buttonAction you call `performSegueWithIdentifier` where you send the object, but then it seems at though you use the sender from `prepareForSegue` when we only sent the object through `performSegueWithIdentifier`

Comment: should I instead be calling `prepareForSegue` in my IBAction? and if so what would I enter for the segue parameter?

Comment: From Apple - " `prepareForSegue:sender:`: *Notifies the view controller that a segue is about to be performed.*" Thus, anything that will initiate a segue action will result in calling this delegate. I used `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` as you might have multiple segues connected to this VC, so you will be able to call specific one via its identifier (which I believe is easier). You can, of course, use whatever you want as long as you please.